# How to setup linting and formatting for VitePress?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, prettier, vitepress

I have a [VitePress](https://vitepress.dev/) project and would like to use [Eslint](https://eslint.org/) and [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) to lint and format code files and especially markdown files. I started with the following scripts and dependencies

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vitepress dev docs",
    "build": "vitepress build docs",
    "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "format": "prettier . --check",
    "format:fix": "prettier . --write"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.56.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.56.0",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.7",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "1.8.1",
    "vitepress": "1.0.0-alpha.65"
  }
}
```

The `prettierrc.json` file contains `{}`. The `.eslintrc.cjs` file contains

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier",
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
};
```

As a sidenote, I know, the plugins for .vue files are missing, but since I don't havy any customizations with Vue yet I don't need it.

Running `npm run format:fix` seems to format my files ( markdown too ) but when running `npm run lint:fix` I get the following error

> No files matching the pattern "." were found.
> Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

although it should find some files. At least the `config.ts` file in the `/docs/.vitepress` folder.

Do you have any ideas what's wrong or missing?

Are there any guides on how to setup Eslint and Prettier for VitePress projects?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to VitePress in general but I can tell you how to lint Markdown using `eslint`:

- Add the package [`eslint-plugin-markdownlint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-markdownlint)
- Add the following to `.eslintrc.cjs`:

```js
module.exports = {
  overrides: [
    {
      extends: ["plugin:markdownlint/recommended"],
      files: ["*.md"],
      parser: "eslint-plugin-markdownlint/parser"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this configuration you will want to ignore Markdown files with Prettier by adding the following to `.prettierignore`:

```
**/*.md
```